# Table is too Wide for Website

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm creating an HTML table in Word Press.  The table is too wide.  I have adjusted the div and the td but it is not working.

```
<table class="tg-table-plain">
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- 
    .tg-left { text-align: left; } 
    .tg-right { text-align: right; } 
    .tg-center { text-align: center; } 
    .tg-bf { font-weight: bold; } 
    .tg-it { font-style: italic; } 
    .tg-table-plain { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; font-size: 33%; font: inherit; } 
    .tg-table-plain td { border: 1px #555 solid; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; } 
-->
```

Comment: <table style="width: 100%;">

Comment: missing your `<style>` tag... `<style><!-- ..... --></style>`

Comment: You could at least have formatted the CSS to be _vaguely_ readable

Comment: Without knowing what data you display in that table, it might be quite impossible to give a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding `width: 100%;` to the tg-table-plain class in your css.  Also be sure to add `<style> </style>` around your CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Table too wide!!! Hmm... So many possibilities as of now.

One thing for sure, add  tag as suggested.

Few days back one friend did simple mistake of adding a row with one cell having text with  commas between each word but no white space after comma. So it is considered as full looong word and table rows were overflowing. might not be in your case but just guess.

Provide parent tags and their style also. You mentioned that you adjusted  tag.